# Change LESSCSS variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

Is it somehow posible to change a LESSCSS variable like

```
@basecolor: #F90;
```

that is later used like this:

```
.myclass {
     color: darken(@basecolor, 10%);
 }
```

with jQuery based on user input from something like the following:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    var color = $("#inputfield").val();
    //Some magic to change the LESS basecolor
});
```

I am using less.js to compile the .less files on the fly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175013/load-less-js-rules-dynamically

Comment: Thanks, but i already had a look at this one, it's about dynamically loading .less files at "runtime" not dynamic content inside .less files

Comment: There's no default way to do this without creating some sort of override in the less.js or alternative methods AFAIK. Here's another more suited to your problem then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274260/programmatically-editing-less-css-code-with-jquery-like-selector-syntax/12487636#12487636

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dinamically changing values in your less file - which is impossible on the client side (aka JavScript), try creating multiple variants in less (something like a theme), and then apply a custom class to an element (body works well).

For example,

```
[style.less]
@green: #00EE00;
@blue: #0000EE;

body {
  &.green { background:@green }
  &.blue { background:@blue }
}

[main.js]
$('#id').on('click', 'a.blue', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('green').addClass('blue')
}
```

Comment: In this case, you can only insert a <style /> with that colour in the html, using JavaScript. For example, you modify a .colour class that contains the colour code, and that applies to the entire page.