# dynamically change LESS variables in page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm trying to use [less.js](http://lesscss.org/) to modify LESS variables dynamically with JavaScript. However, I can't seem to get it to work with `modifyVars`, `watch`, or `refresh`.

I tried putting the stylesheet link tag before loading less.js, using `less.modifyVars({'@bg': '#00ff00'})`, but no change occurs to the background. The less file I'm using is simple:

```
@bg: #000;
body { background-color: @bg; }
```

I also tried putting the stylesheet link tag after less.js, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175013/load-less-js-rules-dynamically?lq=1), and using `less.sheets.push($('#less-link')[0])` followed by a call to `modifyVars` and then `refresh`. No change in the background color.

I also tried commenting out the `@bg: #000;` in the LESS file, then setting it via `modifyVars`. No luck: I end up with a `Less::ParseError: variable @bg is undefined`.

How can I dynamically change LESS variables and have the page appearance update to reflect those changes?

**Edit:** hm, this may be some Rails magic happening. When I loaded my less file, the variable definition was gone and all I saw was `body { background-color: #000; }`. When I switched to using a `<style type="text/less">` block of LESS embedded in the page and used [this override LESS JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/kritzikratzi/BRJXU/1/), I was able to change a variable with `less.Override('@bg', '#00ff00')` and the page's background color immediately changed. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487636/38743). Now I'll try it with less.js using the `<style>` tag instead of `<link>`.

**Edit:** looks like less-1.3.3.min.js wants LESS to be loaded in `link` tags--I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined` when I try to use `modifyVars` and my page looks like this:

```
<style type="text/less">
@bg: #000;
body {
  background-color: @bg;
}
</style>
<script src="/assets/less-1.3.3.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the variable replacing client-side, since I was doing it in a Rails app anyway, I moved it server-side. I'm using the [Ruby bindings for LESS](http://rubydoc.info/gems/less/2.3.2/frames) to parse some LESS that includes my custom variables, rendering the parsed result with `content_type: 'text/css'` and using an AJAX request to add a stylesheet link to the rendered CSS.